# Pull SKU, Manufacturer and custom attribute from Magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to pull a full list of products from the database with the SKU, manufacturer and a custom attribute called 'GTIN'.

I'm really struggling with the custom attribute part.

This statement works to pull the manufacturer and SKU

```
SELECT cpe.sku, m1.manufacturer, 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
INNER JOIN exportview_manufacturer AS m1 ON cpe.entity_id = m1.entity_id
```

My MySQL is very poor and I can't seem to get this custom attribute. I've found the following statement online which I KNOW has all the details I need to make this work but thus far I've been getting my head in a mess trying to implement it

```
SELECT e.entity_id AS product_id, var.value AS product_name
FROM catalog_product_entity e, eav_attribute eav, catalog_product_entity_varchar var
WHERE
e.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id
AND eav.attribute_code = 'gtin'
AND eav.attribute_id = var.attribute_id
AND var.entity_id = e.entity_id
```

I simply need the first statement to also include the 'gtin' column, but joining is where I'm falling short. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one PHP script to get all product and it's attribute. So first create all_product.php file on your Magento root and add below code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);    

require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(); 

 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') // select all attributes
->setPageSize(5000) // limit number of results returned
->setCurPage(1); // set the offset (useful for pagination)

foreach ($collection as $product) {
 echo $product->getName(); //get name
/*you can get any attribue you want like name above. Even you can get all custom attribule for product for that you need to use print_r($collection->getData()) above foreach*/
}
```

Hope it will work.